# Change main Wordpress Menu hover color when close with cursor

Tags: css, wordpress

I work on small Wordpress project, and have a hard time to make menu to work in way i like it. On [homepage](https://micromedico.com/) on my site, menu color is brown, and its not changing hover when close with cursor to some of them. For example when close to cart symbol, color change itself from white to brown like other menu items. So i want to do that to work to all my menu items. Its weird because this problem is just on homepage, on other pages for example [shop](https://micromedico.com/store/) it works in way i want it to be in all site. I found menu CSS class to be defined :

```
 .fusion-is-sticky .fusion-main-menu > ul > li.current-menu-ancestor > a, .fusion-is-sticky .fusion-main-menu > ul > li.current-menu-item > a, .fusion-is-sticky .fusion-main-menu > ul > li.current-menu-parent > a, .fusion-is-sticky .fusion-main-menu > ul > li.current_page_item > a, .fusion-is-sticky .fusion-main-menu > ul > li:not(.fusion-middle-logo-menu-logo) > a:hover, .fusion-main-menu > ul > li.current-menu-ancestor > a, .fusion-main-menu > ul > li.current-menu-item > a, .fusion-main-menu > ul > li.current-menu-parent > a, .fusion-main-menu > ul > li.current_page_item > a, .fusion-main-menu > ul > li:not(.fusion-middle-logo-menu-logo) > a:hover, .fusion-main-menu > ul > li:not(.fusion-middle-logo-menu-logo):hover > a 
background-color:#ceb19c;
}
```

when change `background-color:#ceb19c;` to `background-color:#fff;` all menu items is chaning to white background, but when close it it, not changing to brown like works in shop page. Someone to help me how to fix this?

Answer (score 1):

You can probably use this css rule that targets the top level links in the nav when on the home page.

```
body.home a.fusion-top-level-link:hover {
    background-color: #fff !important;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The CSS is the same whether on hover or not hovered using that `#ceb19c` hex value. You need to separate out your hover colour to be something like:

```
body.home .menu-item .fusion-top-level-link:hover{
 background: #fff (or any color you want it to be)
}
```

This should solve the problem